# Custom tpl.php render issues

Tags: theming

I'm in a custom tpl.php file. I'm also highly confused!

This line renders nothing...

```
render($content['field_subtitle']['0']['#markup']);
```

This line drops the subtitle as expected but in the Devel_Themer formatting.

```
kpr($content['field_subtitle']['0']['#markup']);
```

I'm trying to custom-theme a content type in a custom node.tpl.php file. Everything should work as expected... but, of course... it's not. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you are trying to print the value of field_subtitle, you shoud use field_view_field() function. For example: <?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_subtitle')); ?>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use:

```
print $content['field_subtitle']['0']['#markup'];
```

or else just

```
print render($content['field_subtitle']);
```

Comment: Also, you could just dump everything on the screen by using something like `print '<pre>' . check_plain(print_r($content, 1)) . '</pre>';` if you're having trouble figuring out what is or isn't available to you...

Comment: print render($content['field_subtitle']);
is the right way to do it - it checks for sub-elements hidden before in template with [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7)

Comment: I'll tell you what it is...

Comment: I haven't touched PHP in a few years (I've been working on my deltoids, lol) and I forgot to print before render... so I was just rendering... ugh.

Comment: @randomblink Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped to solve the problem, you can do that by clicking the tick mark next to the answer :)